Is ROS2 deterministic when composing multiple nodes in a single-threaded executor?
I have 1 talker publishing messages on 2 topics at various rates using timer callbacks (e.g. 1 every 17 ms, 1 every 50 ms). Accordingly, I have 2 listeners listening to 1 topic each.
To make things deterministic (same message ordering, obviously same message contents on every run, etc.), I plan to model all these nodes as components and to compose them into a single-threaded executor. Reading Executors, I should think this is sufficient. Considering existing other discussions (Fast, accurate, robust replay in ROS2, Deterministic ROS 2 Callback Scheduling), I guess, though, that this component composition may be insufficient or even incorrect for deterministic behavior, hence the question:
Is ROS2 deterministic when composing multiple nodes in a single-threaded executor?
I can imagine that the timer callbacks may jitter. My counter-measure here: Relying on a single 1ms timer and doing my own publication scheduling inside this callback (if (counter % 17) == 0 { ... if (counter % 50) == 0 {.
Is there anything else to consider? Or is this setup fully deterministic?
Note 1: I don't want to consider the wall time vs. simulation time topic here. Let's assume for this question that none of the components relies on the time.
Note 2: In case it matters, the middleware implementation is the default one (jazzy on Ubuntu 24.04).

I would not say that it would be guaranteed to be full deterministic. There are a lot of things that might interact with the system. Any other node or introspection tools running. Other loads on the system. The undefined callbacks of the listeners might have effects. As well as cpu and other resource loads etc.
Even just a single timer isn't guaranteed to be deterministic on most oses, with the vagaries of the system scheduler. For full determinism you need to step up to a fully realtime system and program every piece to stay compliant with specific limits.

We may have a different definition of determinism. In my case, it's about getting identical outputs given identical inputs on consecutive runs. While multiple timers may yield different results due to possible different call sequences, how would a single timer be non-deterministic? Similarly, introspection or other nodes will lead to different run times, but how shall this affect determinism?

If you algorithms take deltaT into account jitter in the timer can cause a different result, thus it's non-deterministic. It's very hard to have a system that doesn't interact with the outside would at all. Any system call will break the assumption that all inputs are the same.

As I wrote in the question, we assume for the question that no algorithm relies on time. The use case is replaying a recorded measurement deterministically. So there's no interaction with the outside world in that use case, nor with any time component. My rephrased question could be whether ROS2 itself is deterministic - given a deterministic algorithm solely depending on inputs?
